# Is there way to submit SOAP request to gRPC endpoints?

Tags: json, soap, grpc

We have used [gRPC-JSON trans-coder](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_filters/grpc_json_transcoder_filter) to submit JSON request to GRPC. Due to the different 3rd party services, Now I have to find a way to submit SOAP request to the GRPC. Please advise me.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to post a question on https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy to find out if Envoy supports SOAP at all. If not, probably nobody has looked at mapping SOAP requests to gRPC (with or without Envoy).